# Traer a un formulario de modificación, datos para editarlos

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, adminlte

[image: Quiero que los datos del usuario se muestran aqui para que el cliente no tenga que escribir todos los datos que va a modificar]Tengo una plataforma de administración y una tabla de registros (Todo va bien), la cuestion es.... tengo un boton que obtiene el ID del registro y con ese ID lo modifico ¿Como logro que traiga los datos de ese registro en lugar de dejar el formulario en blanco? para que asi el cliente no tenga que escribir todos los datos del usuario a modificar

De antemano gracias.

Comment: hola, pienso que con ese id haces una consulta a tu base de datos y obtienes la tupla que necesitas, y usando javascript puedes añadir los valores a tu html, si pudieras poner un poco de tu codigo HTML y PHP para tener mejor idea de lo que necesitas

Comment: Por favor podrias añadir el codigo HTML es necesario para poder ayudarte, mostrando tu codigo PHP claro esta

Comment: @sgClaudia98, en un momento lo subo

Comment: No le pongas cerrado al título de la pregunta, con marcar como aceptada la respuesta alcanza

Comment: Thankies.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer; cuando haces el llamado a la pagina que esta mostrando tu formulario debes pasar un parámetro en este caso el id del usuario que quieres modificar luego en el visor del formulario se harán los cambios pertinentes luego de eso ese formulario con el nuevo contenido se posteara en un script el cual hará la inserción en la base de datos.

Llamado a form con parametros -> form.php -> post.php

> *Este es un esquema básico, hoy existen maneras asincronas de enviar post via ajax en cualquier momento, pero para entender esta es la manera mas sencilla.*

La primera parte creo que ya la tienes resuelta hacer el llamado al formulario con algun parametro ej: **form.php?pid=var**, donde var es un numero con el cual identificaras el id del usuario esto es via GET, también esta el método POST, pero eso debes determinarlo tu, que método usaras,así que pasaré al form.php: hoy por hoy también hay maneras de trabajar esto usando algún framework, pero para entender esto haré uso del famoso y nunca bien ponderado código espagueti.
en el form.php hacemos el encabezado como html y dentro de el ponemos código php para rescatar las variables.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   ... codigo php que rescata variables de la base 
?>
<form  method="post" name="forminfo1" id="forminfo1" action="post.php">
<input name="numUsuario" id="numUsuario" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

En la sección del código php creamos nuestra conexión y recibimos el parametro
para hacer la consulta en nuestra base.

```
<?php

@$server='';
@$dbname='';
@$dbuser=''; 
@$dbpass='';

// 1. Create a database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
// recibimos la varible la cual identifica el set de datos que traeremos
$pid=$_GET['pid'];  

$query  = sprintf("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idusuario=".$pid); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $idUser = $row["idusuario"]; 
        $nomUser = $row["nombre"];
        }
?>
```

Para mostrar los valores en los campos input html es necesario hacer un echo desde php con los datos rescatados, en el parámetro value del input se debe hacer el

```
echo <input name="numUsuario" id="numUsuario" value="<?=$idUser;?>">
```

adjunto código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

@$server='';
@$dbname='';
@$dbuser=''; 
@$dbpass='';

// 1. Create a database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
// recibimos la varible la cual identifica el set de datos que traeremos
$pid=$_GET['pid']; 

$query  = sprintf("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idusuario=".$pid); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $idUser = $row["idusuario"]; 
        $nomUser = $row["nombre"];
        }
?>
    <form  method="post" name="forminfo1" id="forminfo1"  action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="numUsuario" id="numUsuario" value="<?=$idUser;?>">
    <input type="text" name="nombreUsuario" id="nomUsuario" value="<?=$nomUser;?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Post" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Posterior a esto con las variables ya en el formulario podemos modificar los datos y luego hacer el llamado mediante submit al action del formulario.
en post.php recibiras los nuevos datos modificados y mediante este script haras la modificacion en la base de datos.

post.php

```
<?php
//archivo de conexion
include("../config.php");
//clase para enviar respuesta de verificacion
$respuesta = new stdClass();
    $query  =  sprintf("UPDATE usuarios SET nombre='%s' WHERE idusuarios=%s",
            trim($_REQUEST['nomUsuario'])), trim($_REQUEST["id"]));
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);                        
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
     $respuesta->value="Registro Guardado";
    } 
    else {
        $respuesta->value="Hubo problemas al crear el registro, intente nuevamente";
    } 
 echo json_encode(array("data"=>$respuesta));  
?>
```

Espero que esta pequeña guia te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Inyección de SQL por todas partes, eeeeewww. De ese problema no te libra sprintf por cierto.

Comment: Siempre es mas fácil destruir que construir.

Comment: Claro. Por eso es nuestra responsabilidad no hacérselo tan fácil al que quiera tomar nuestros descuidos como áreas que pueda explotar. El ego es debilidad.

Comment: Podrías Ilustrarnos?

Comment: Ya es 2020, deja el cinismo y actualízate, fuentes hay muchas pero siquiera empieza por la wikipedia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL#PHP

Comment: Y aquí mismo hay ya esa investigación si te esfuerzas un poco https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Comment: Gracias, me esforzaré lo que más pueda.